# Divisors on projective bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, birational-geometry, projective-geometry, divisors

Let $\pi:X = \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^n$ be a projective bundle, where $\mathcal{E}$ is a rank two vector bundle over $\mathbb{P}^n$.

If $n = 0$ then $X = \mathbb{P}^1$, and for $n = 1$ we have that $X$ is a Hirzebruch surface. In both cases $-K_X$ is effective.

Is there an example, with $n\geq 2$, of a projective bundle $X = \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^n$ such that $-K_X$ is not effective?

Answer (score 2):

There is a formula, $K_X\simeq \mathcal{O}_X(-2)\otimes \pi^*\det \mathcal{E}^{\vee}\otimes \pi^*K_{\mathbb{P}^n}$.

(More generally, for rank $r+1$ bundle, replace -2 by $-r-1$ in the above formula.)

Now $\pi^*K_{\mathbb{P}^n}\simeq \pi^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-n-1).$
So
$$K_X\simeq \mathcal{O}_X(-2)\otimes \pi^*\det \mathcal{E}^{\vee}\otimes\pi^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-n-1)=\mathcal{O}_X(-2)\otimes \pi^*(\det \mathcal{E}^{\vee}\otimes\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-n-1))$$

Hence $$-K_X\simeq \mathcal{O}_X(2)\otimes \pi^*(\det \mathcal{E}\otimes\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(n+1))$$

So $-K_X$ is always effective as long as the line bundle on the RHS above has a non-zero section.

**Added** (I will leave this here for future readers): When I wrote this, I wasn't aware of Hartshorne's conjecture for rank 2 bundles. Thanks to @YosemiteStan for the enlightenment! See YosemiteStan's and abx's comment below for more details.

Comment: Thank you. Twisting $\mathcal{E}$ by a sufficiently positive line bundle on $\mathbb{P}^n$ couldn't we make $\text{det}(\mathcal{E})$ positive? If so it seems that $-K_X$ is always effective independently from what $\mathcal{E}\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^n$ is. Is this the case?

Comment: @GDR Yes. That is correct. Projectivization of $\mathcal{E}$ and that of twist of $\mathcal{E}$ by a line bundle are isomorphic. So $-K_X$ is always effective.

Comment: @Evans Gambit: This is definitely wrong. You are confusing the tautological line bundle $\mathscr{O}_X(1)$ and the pull back $\pi ^*\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)$.

Comment: @abx Thanks a lot for pointing out the mistake. I have made the correction. Let me know if you spot anything other errors.

Comment: If you push forward the right hand side of the final equation you should get (I think??) $\mathrm{Sym}^2(\mathcal{E}^\vee)\otimes \mathrm{det}(\mathcal{E})\otimes \mathcal{O}(n+1)$. When $\mathcal{E}$ is a sum of line bundles it looks like that always has a section (another way to see this should be to observe that these projective bundles are toric I think). On the other hand, I doubt these always have a section when n=2, but if you believe Hartshorne's conjecture on rank 2 bundles then perhaps it is true when n is at least 7.

Comment: @Evans Gambit: Then again if we twist $\mathcal{E}$ by a sufficiently positive line bundle we get that $-K_X$ is always effective. So why do you write "as long as the line bundle on the RHS above has a non-zero section"?

Comment: Of course, twisting $\mathscr{E}$ by a line bundle doesn't change $-K_X$. See the comment of @Yosemite Stan, which expresses the problem in terms of vector bundles on $\Bbb{P}^n$.

Comment: @Evans Gambit: In your last formula if I take $n = 1$ and $\mathcal{E} = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}\oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(e)$ with $e\geq 0$, $E$ the negative section, $F$ the fiber, and $H$ a section of $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$, then $H = E + eF$. So $-K_X \sim 2E + 2eF +(e+2)F$. However, the right expression should be $-K_X \sim 2E + (e+2)F$.

Comment: @Yosemite Stan: yes, if $\mathcal{E}$ splits then $X$ is toric and $−K_X$ is the sum of the torus invariant divisors, so it is effective. If I understood your comment you are saying that there should be a non splitting rank two vector bundle $\mathcal{E}$ on $\mathbb{P}^2$ such that $−K_X$ is not effective. Did I get it right? Also I think that $\text{Sym}^2(\mathcal{E}^{\vee})\otimes\text{det}(\mathcal{E})\otimes\mathcal{O}(n+1)$ has rank three not two.

Comment: @Evans Gambit: By the way I think in your last formula $\det(\mathcal{E})$ should be $\det(\mathcal{E}^{\vee})$. Summing-up what would it be an explicit example of $\mathcal{E}\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^2$ with $-K_{\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})}$ not effective?